Want to fetch tokens from wallet on website, like if someone connected on webpage then all tokens user have in wallet should display on website
I want to display tokens from user wallet when he connectes on website, and then he can convert all his tokens into a single token

If you want to fetch all token accounts owned by a wallet, you can use the getTokenAccountsByOwner RPC call:
curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
      "4Qkev8aNZcqFNSRhQzwyLMFSsi94jHqE8WNVTJzTP99F",
      {
        "mint": "3wyAj7Rt1TWVPZVteFJPLa26JmLvdb1CAKEFZm3NY75E"
      },
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'

Copied from https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettokenaccountsbyowner
